# Toggle issue with shopping cart jPayPalCart.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle, jquery-events

I am having difficulty with a jPayPalCart.js toggling the myCart div.  I have the cart functioning perfectly.  When I load the page I am able to toggle the cart by clicking on the shopping cart in the top right.  I have another button that I have added to the myCart code that says "Close" and closes the myCart div.

However, when I add an item to the shopping cart,(only the first item on the demo page actually adds an item) this function no longer is triggered when the cart icon is clicked.  I do not see any errors in the console of my browser.

It only works again when the page gets refreshed. How can I make it so that I don't have to refresh the page?

Would really appreciate someone helping me trouble shoot this, it's been driving me crazy for two days.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".menu").activeMenu();
     $("#myCart").hide();

     // Create a basic cart
     $("#myCart").PayPalCart({
         business: 'mypaypal@myemail.com',
         notifyURL: 'http://www.diditwork.com/payment.aspx',
         virtual: false,             //set to true where you are selling virtual items such as downloads
         quantityupdate: true,       //set to false if you want to disable quantity updates in the cart 
         currency: 'CAD',            //set to your trading currency - see PayPal for valid options
         currencysign: '$',          //set the currency symbol
         minicartid: 'minicart',     //element to show the number of items and net value
         persitdays: 0               //set to -1 for cookie-less cart for single page of products, 
         // 0 (default) persits for the session, 
         // x (number of days) the basket will persits between visits
     });

$(".cartImg").click(function () {
    alert("your hitting it");
    $("#myCart").toggle();
});
$(".closeCart").click(function () {
    alert("your hitting it");
    $("#myCart").hide();
});

 });
```

[Demo Site here for example](http://w3.ookie.com/shop.aspx)

[Reference to script I am using](http://www.ultimateweb.co.uk/jpaypalcart-jquery-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Still looking around I was able to find a solution.  by using .live(), modifying the click function this seems to work.  If you view the API documentation you will see the details, but basically, the cart was updating "dynamically" which changed the properties of the object.  .live() "refreshes" this state allowing the object to be recognized within the script.

```
$(".cartImg").live("click", function () {
    alert("your hitting it");
    $("#myCart").toggle();
});
$(".closeCart").live("click", function () {
    alert("your hitting it");
    $("#myCart").hide();
});
```